# can i bind two grid views to one data source with specific code depending on the sender(grid view)?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have two gridviews that call the same stored proc. so I would like to use one objectdatasource. The problem is that when I get back the table I need to sort it differently for each grid view. So I would need to know which gridview called the stored proc. any idea?

Comment: stored proc and objectdatasource? Can you show some code - how do you currently bind grid to data?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

In each of the DataGrids, in the Column XAML, set `SortMemberPath="NameOfProperty"`. You can also add it in the Designer -> DataGrid->Properties->Columns->SortMemberPath